# Golang / GO : I want to read data from oracle database in golang but outside TDM-GCC-64 folder in short in my curent working directory

Tags: sql, goracle

I am new on golang and currently, I am trying to read data from Oracle DB, but when I try to import library goracle.v2 it gives error `exec: gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%`, so, for now, I have downloaded TDM-GCC-64 complier and currently created one working directory there and it is also working
But I need the same functionality should work when I write a project in some other directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer it is actually simple

1) you just have to add "TDM-GCC-64" 's bin folder path into Environment variable in my case it is `“C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin"`

2) Open a new command prompt and then check gcc version using command `gcc --version` if it shows version then you have done with it.

Now you just need to import --> go get gopkg.in/goracle.v2 and it will work